# Discordjs v14.8 | Reaction Buttons doesn't work after bot restarts

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a bot with ticket and reactrole features, but whenever a new update comes out and I have to restart the bot, I have to redo the ticket and reactrole features.I did some research but I couldn't figure it out.  I set my files as follows.

**commands/ticket.js**

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "@discordjs/builders";
import {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
  ChannelType,
  EmbedBuilder,
  PermissionsBitField,
} from "discord.js";

export default {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ticket")
    .setDescription("Ticket Açmak için!")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator),
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const button = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("button")
        .setEmoji("")
        .setLabel("Destek Talebi Oluştur")
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
    );

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("Purple")
      .setTitle("Destek Talebi")
      .setDescription(
        "Destek talebi oluşturmak için aşağıdaki **Destek Talebi Oluştur** butonuna tıklayınız."
      );

    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [button] });

    const collector =
      await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();

    collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
      await i.update({ embeds: [embed], components: [button] });

      const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
        name: `${i.user.tag} Ticket`,
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        parent: "1071088629469945876",
      });

      channel.permissionOverwrites.create(i.user.id, {
        ViewChannel: true,
        SendMessages: true,
      });

      channel.permissionOverwrites.create(channel.guild.roles.everyone, {
        ViewChannel: false,
        SendMessages: false,
      });

      channel.send({
        content: `${i.user} destek talebiniz oluşturulmuştur. Lütfen destek almak istediğiniz konu hakkında genel bir bilgi veriniz. En kısa zamanda yetkili birisi talebinize yanıt verecektir. **Not:** Taleplere soru eklenmeyen ve yanıtlanan destek taleplerisilinmektedir.`,
      });
      i.user
        .send(
          `${i.user}, ${i.guild.name} destek talebiniz başarıyla oluşturulmuştur.`
        )
        .catch((err) => {
          return;
        });
      //Reload
      await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed], components: [button] });
    });
  },
};
```

**commands/reactionRoles.js**

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "@discordjs/builders";
import { PermissionsBitField } from "discord.js";
import fs from "fs";
import { join, dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

function getData() {
  const command = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("reaction-roles")
    .setDescription("Reaction Role Messege")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option.setName("link").setDescription("Message link.").setRequired(true)
    )
    .addRoleOption((option) =>
      option.setName("role").setDescription(`Role`).setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option.setName("emoji-id").setDescription("Emoji ID.").setRequired(true)
    );
  return command;
}

export default {
  data: getData(),

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const messageLink = interaction.options.getString("link");
    const role = interaction.options.getRole("role");
    const emojiId = interaction.options.getString("emoji-id");
    const list = client.guilds.cache.get(process.env.SERVER_ID);

    const ids = messageLink.match(/\d+/g);
    const message =
      (await client.channels.cache
        .get(ids[1])
        ?.messages.fetch(ids[2])
        .catch((err) => null)) ?? null;

    client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => {
      if (emoji.id === emojiId) {
        message.react(emoji);
      }
    });
    const rawData = fs.readFileSync(
      join(__dirname, "..", "..", "data/reactionRankForNovels.json")
    );
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(rawData);
    jsonData.push({ role: role, emoji: emojiId, messageLink: messageLink });

    fs.writeFileSync(
      join(__dirname, "..", "..", "data/reactionRankForNovels.json"),
      JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2)
    );

    const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ dispose: true });

    collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
      const member = list.members.cache.find((memb) => memb.id === user.id);
      const givenRole = await jsonData.find(
        (item) => item.emoji === reaction.emoji.id
      );

      if (givenRole?.role?.id.length) {
        member.roles.add(givenRole.role.id);
      }
    });

    collector.on("remove", async (reaction, user) => {
      const member = list.members.cache.find((memb) => memb.id === user.id);
      const givenRole = await jsonData.find(
        (item) => item.emoji === reaction.emoji.id
      );
      if (givenRole?.role?.id.length) {
        member.roles.remove(givenRole?.role?.id);
      }
    });
  },
};
```

**index.js**

```
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
import config from "./config.js";
import logger from "./logger.js";

import { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } from "discord.js";
import { REST } from "@discordjs/rest";
import { Routes } from "discord-api-types/v10";
import { join, dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const client = new Client({
  shards: "auto",
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Reaction,
    Partials.GuildScheduledEvent,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.ThreadMember,
  ],
});

client.commands = new Collection();

const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(config.token);

const commands = [];

// Command autoload
readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).forEach(async (file) => {
  const command = await import(`./commands/${file}`).then((c) => c.default);

  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
  client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
});

// Event autoload
readdirSync(join(__dirname, "events")).forEach(async (file) => {
  const event = await import(`./events/${file}`).then((x) => x.default);

  if (event.once) {
    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
  } else {
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
  }
});

client.on("ready", async () => {
  try {
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(client.user.id), {
      body: commands,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
  }

  logger.info(`${client.user.username} Aktif Edildi!`);
});

// Process Events
const unhandledEventHandler = (e) => logger.error(e);

process.on("unhandledRejection", unhandledEventHandler);
process.on("uncaughtException", unhandledEventHandler);
process.on("uncaughtExceptionMonitor", unhandledEventHandler);

client.login(config.token);
```

Thank you!

I tried some changes on indexjs but is not working. I wanna make the reactions work after reset the bot.

Comment: What do you mean, "redo"?

Comment: @CloudWatcher again going that channel and write /ticket and create new post for ticket. Also create the reaction post and add all icons again

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a **Collector**, consider using an `interactionCreate` event itself.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (i) => {
    // only listen to that one button
    if (!i.isButton() && i.customId !== 'button') return;

    const channel = await i.guild.channels.create({
        name: `${i.user.tag} Ticket`,
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        parent: "1071088629469945876",
    });

    channel.permissionOverwrites.create(i.user.id, {
        ViewChannel: true,
        SendMessages: true,
    });

    channel.permissionOverwrites.create(channel.guild.roles.everyone, {
        ViewChannel: false,
        SendMessages: false,
    });

    channel.send({
        content: `${i.user} destek talebiniz oluşturulmuştur. Lütfen destek almak istediğiniz konu hakkında genel bir bilgi veriniz. En kısa zamanda yetkili birisi talebinize yanıt verecektir. **Not:** Taleplere soru eklenmeyen ve yanıtlanan destek taleplerisilinmektedir.`,
    });
    i.user
        .send(
            `${i.user}, ${i.guild.name} destek talebiniz başarıyla oluşturulmuştur.`
        )
        .catch((err) => {
            return;
        });
})
```